# cannot open jar file by double clicking on macOS

Tags: java, macos, jar

I created an executable jar with intellij and ran it fine via the terminal, however whenever I try clicking on the jar inorder to run it I get a message:

```
The Java JAR file "mazegame.jar" could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error or messages.
```

And this is somehow exclusive to my mac system, on windows it works fine. I have the java launcher set as default, so I don't see why it should not work.

would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

While coursing the item for example program.jar:

1. Double click and open list of options that can be used
2. press option > choose open

Then you can open it

Comment: While helping individuals, we also try to produce a permanent source of future help for others - so answers that produce a tangible record are preferred. Before offering 1:1 help, read [this Meta post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280603) and reconsider making the effort to document the answer.